# CSS / JS - Убрать эффект скролла в мобильной версии

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css3

Верстаю страницу чата. Необходимо сделать ее как в мобильной версии вк (пример: https://m.vk.com/mail?act=show&peer=8). По сути должны быть два блока:

- Блок с сообщениями
- Блок с textarea прижатый к низу страницы

Проблема заключается в том, что при скроллинге страницы на мобильных устройствах (в частности iOS Safari), скролл заходит за пределы прижатого к низу блока с textarea.

[image: Залезает за края]

Должно быть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал использовать JavaScript (touchmove e.preventDefault), но это блокирует скроллинг внутри блока с сообщениями и внутри textarea.

Пробовал играться с настройками CSS, но безуспешно. Вариант с JavaScript (touchmove e.preventDefault) подошел бы идеально, если бы позволял использовать скролл внутри блока сообщений и textarea.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.scrollable {
  background-color: #fef;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.textarea {
  background-color: pink;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="scrollable">
    Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some
    text
    <br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text
    <br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>Some text<br>
  </div>
  <div class="textarea">
    <textarea>Textarea</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```